# Downloading files from amazon s3 that have been uploaded by a third party

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My problem is this. I have files that are being added to my S3 bucket from a third party. Now if I try to download these files from the command line they are corrupt or encrypted. But if i download them individually from the S3 console they are fine. (I don't have encryption enabled either)

**So, my question is this:
Is it possible to download objects from an Amazon S3 bucket that have been uploaded by a third party?**

I've read just about everything I can on this and cant find an answer as to why this is the case. Here is the bucket policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name-here/*"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Example of file contents when encrypted:
^*�^H^H^@��P^B�doc.0.js^@�T[o�0^X�+^^�^FH�
pM�ֆj҆:mZ�=M�DNb.^S^Ad��ٴ�>^S.!YՆ^Gۆ^>�ㆌp䆌-册`��^[�ΆVن^V,sZ
7JE^S��Z소sv�첕H^C^_Awʲֲ!HY��"� �^A$�$
<7�"�u{�l^OZ�ѧ)>�7Ч�.3ʇ^HۃQ
��?gTS?2J���S�l%z^?�9gB0nHh�^UI`��B� �^]��^t�%�-KQ^KN�3^W*�����[ہށ�Ӂ5
偌IV^X����偌^]���2�ȁ~>>>:�B,^\^S�*|nہ^@x၌遌쁌�u��
�hE^[��]�=Ն��~��h�teԆzꆌ�#x�Gyǆ&Sw8^F]d}D�^^ z2��Q
A^Vk^E�f ^U%�����
+^D̊^U{�^\kꊌ�/�ꑁ�?푁^E6O!gUN�L3�o?�^*�L�n�ё^[^Q3��בx�[py�\�^FR�^P�
���,�����>�t�V^Z���<��^?iLW^X^Y^E^@^@

Answer (score 0):

If a third party tool encrypt your file and upload it, you have to decrypt it in the same way and with the same key.